# update Text (UTF8 String) on MySQL with Command

Tags: mysql

probelm in insert Text (Json format with UTF8 String) on MySQL with Command

my Command:

```
update blog set theme_data = 'test تست'
```

after update result in field is 'test'

stracher Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `theme_data` text COMMENT 'Json',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85977 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem from PhpStorm Terminal.

Bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36563#u=1495375066997